# Mysql order by sorting not working as expected descending

Tags: mysql, join, select

i am facing a a very strange behavior regarding mysql orderby sort, I am trying to sort the records by fee_range high to low which is being computed in run time first 3,4 rows have lowest values and then order by takes effect and and further all records are sorted as expected is there any thing that i am missing?

here is the query that i am running

```
SELECT `ddd`.`ID`, CONCAT(ddd.title, " ", ddd.name) AS name, `ddd`.`url`, `ddd`.`doc_gender`, `ddd`.`edu_degrees`, TRIM(BOTH ", " FROM ddd.specializations) AS specializations, `ddd`.`tel_appointments`, CONCAT("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mdpk/images/profile-pics/doctors/", ddd.profile_image) AS profile_image, `ddd`.`yearsofexperience`, IF(MIN(IF(daas.fee > 0, `daas`.`fee`, NULL)) = MAX(IF(daas.fee > 0, `daas`.`fee`, NULL)), MIN(IF(daas.fee > 0, `daas`.`fee`, NULL)), CONCAT(MIN(IF(daas.fee > 0, `daas`.`fee`, NULL)), "-", MAX(IF(daas.fee > 0, `daas`.`fee`, NULL)))) AS fee_range, `dhdtl`.`locality`, `dhdtl`.`city`, `ddd`.`star_rating`, `ddd`.`is_paying`, `ddd`.`divert_to_cc`, `ddd`.`patient_records`, IF(MAX(daas.allow_online_booking + daas.has_active_subs) = 2, 1, 0) AS is_bookable, MAX(daas.has_active_subs) AS has_active_subscription, `ddd`.`verified_patients`, `ddd`.`average_wait_time`, (ddd.positive_reviews + ddd.negative_reviews) AS total_reviews, IF(ddd.verified_patients > 0 AND 
            ddd.positive_reviews + ddd.negative_reviews > 0 AND 
            ddd.positive_reviews + ddd.negative_reviews > 0 AND 
            (ddd.is_paying = 1 OR 1 = 0), ROUND(ddd.positive_reviews * 100 / (ddd.positive_reviews + ddd.negative_reviews), 0), 0) AS recommendation_percentage
FROM `doc_doc_details` AS `ddd`
JOIN `doc_specialization_relation` `dsr` ON `dsr`.`user_id` = `ddd`.`ID`
JOIN `doc_hosp_doctor` `dhd` ON `ddd`.`ID` = `dhd`.`user_id`
JOIN `doc_app_adv_settings` `daas` ON `dhd`.`hospital_id` = `daas`.`subs_id` AND `daas`.`prov_id`=`ddd`.`ID`
JOIN `doc_hospital_details` `dhdtl` ON `dhd`.`hospital_id` = `dhdtl`.`hosp_detail_id`
WHERE `dhdtl`.`country_id` = 1
AND `dhdtl`.`city_id` = '1'
AND `dsr`.`specialization_id` IN('72')
AND `ddd`.`published` = 1
GROUP BY `ddd`.`ID`
ORDER BY `has_active_subscription` DESC, MAX(fee_range) DESC, `ddd`.`manual_web_rank`, `ddd`.`computed_web_rank`, `dhd`.`is_primary` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

here are the results

[image]

any help regarding this issue would be really appreciated

Comment: what is the reason for down vote? feel free to ask if something seems not understandable

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CONCAT`-function inside the fee_range-column turns the column into a character column (causing ordering by alphabetical order) and you are ordering the column with `MAX(fee_range)` whereas it should be just `fee_range`.

Comment: i got a way around slaakso sometimes just a minimal input can give you a way out of a problem instead of down voting and discouraging some one thank you so much for giving your time to my question and understating the situation

Comment: @Awaisfiaz it was a valid question and no need for downvote. You can improve the future questions by adding sample data and using text (not images) in the questions. Use text or better yet, use SQLFiddle/dbfiddle/db-fiddle).

Comment: sure @slaakso i'll keep that in mind for future question thanks again